# Error in creating a function to perform ttests on multiple continuous variables

Tags: r

So I'm trying to create a function that will take in a string of continuous variables, a categorical variable and a dataframe and output a table that includes, for each continuous variable: mean group1, mean group2, teststat, confidence interval, p-value.

What is currently here gives me the error:  Error in model.frame.default(formula = var ~ class, data = data) :  variable lengths differ (found for 'class')

I would love any feedback on how to fix this error and make this function do what I like. I want to make this function way more substantial and flexible, but I can't even get the basic version (handling multiple variables) to work.

THANKS!

```
#Continuous must be an object of the form:
   #vars<-c("cont1", "cont2", "cont3", etc)
#CREATE DATA
cat1<-sample(c(1,2), 100, replace=T)
cont1<-rnorm(100, 25, 8)
cont2<-rnorm(100, 0, 1)
cont3<-rnorm(100, 6, 14.23)
cont4<-rnorm(100, 25, 8)*runif(5, 0.1, 1)
one<-data.frame(cat1, cont1, cont2, cont3, cont4)

#FUNCTION
two.group.comp<-function(continvars,class,data){
attach(data)

descriptives<-function(var){
 test<-t.test(var~class, data)
 means<-data.frame(test[5])
 mean1<-means[1,1]
 mean2<-means[2,1]
 teststatbig<-data.frame(test[1])
 teststat<-teststatbig[1,1]
 conf<-data.frame(test[4])
 lconf<-conf[1,1]
 uconf<-conf[2,1]
 pvalues<-data.frame(test[3])
 pvalue<-pvalues[1,1]

 variablename<-deparse(substitute(var))

 entry<-data.frame(variablename,mean1,mean2,lconf,uconf,teststat,pvalue)
 }  
 var<-data.frame(continvars)
 table<<-sapply(var,descriptives)
  detach(data)
}  
#VARIABLES
continvars<-c("cont1", "cont2", "cont3")
#CALL TO FUNCTION
two.group.comp(continvars=continvars, class=cat1, data=one)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
two.group.comp <- function(continvars,class,data){
  get.stats <- function(x,cat){
    f  <- unique(cat)
    x1 <- x[cat==f[1]]
    x2 <- x[cat==f[2]]
    tt <- t.test(x1,x2)
    smry        <- c(tt$estimate,tt$statistic,p=tt$p.value)
    names(smry) <- c("mean.1","mean.2","t","p")
    return(smry)
  }
  result <- do.call(rbind,lapply(data[,continvars],get.stats,cat=class))
  return(result)
}
# create sample dataset
set.seed(1)
cat1 <-sample(c(1,2), 100, replace=T)
cont1<-rnorm(100, 25, 8)
cont2<-rnorm(100, 0, 1)
cont3<-rnorm(100, 6, 14.23)
cont4<-rnorm(100, 25, 8)*runif(5, 0.1, 1)
one  <-data.frame(cat1, cont1, cont2, cont3, cont4)
continvars<-c("cont1", "cont2", "cont3")
# call the function...
two.group.comp(continvars,cat1,one)
#           mean.1      mean.2          t          p
# cont1 24.4223859 25.33275704 -0.6024497 0.54827955
# cont2  0.0330148  0.01168979  0.1013519 0.91947827
# cont3 10.5784201  4.00651493  2.4183031 0.01747468
```

Working from the inside out:

1. `get.stats(...)` takes a single column of `data`, splits it into `x1` and `x2` according to `cat`, runs the t-test, and returns the summary statistics as a named vector.
2. `lapply(...)` passes the `continvars` columns of `data` to `get.stats(...)` one at a time.
3. `do.call(rbind,...)` binds together the set of vectors returned from `lapply(...)`, row-wise, to generate the final result table.

This will work also if you pass column numbers instead of column names.

A piece of advice: the way you have it set up, you pass the *column names* of the continuous variables, but you pass the grouping factor as a vector. It would be cleaner if you pass the column name of the grouping factor.

Comment: That does exactly what I want, thank you! I was able to use that as a base and made a pretty useful little function out of it. 

But I'm stuck. I've made a separate post since it's a different issue.

If you are able to, I'd love some more help. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313731/how-to-combine-a-set-of-tables-with-a-single-row-when-trying-to-summarize-freque